# Multiple GET requests with Angular 4/5

Tags: angular

I'm doing a query in an API (SWAPI). Return is an object with all the information of the Star Wars characters. So far so good. But within this object, I have some sub-levels that are arrays and that besides some information, also has another URL that I need to consult to be able to print on the screen. The problem is that I'm not sure how to do this other query. To simplify, follow the image of the return:
[image]

Here is the get of the service:

```
getData(page?: string): Observable<any[]> {
if(page){
  this.URL = page;
}
return this.http.get(this.URL)
.map((response: Response) => <any[]>response.json())
.catch(this.handleError);
```

}

I know there is a way to do with flatMap and forkJoin. I even tried, but I did not get the expected result

Follow this link: [rxjs-observable](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/#respond)

But I still could not.

Comment: It could help if you provided a better example of what specific data you're interested in.

Comment: OK.
I want all the data of the results, besides, I also want all the movies, species and vehicles. Note that movies, species, and vehicles are arrays that contain a URL. I need to get the data from these urls as well. Did you get it?

Comment: See the mergeMap example at https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Comment: Thanks friend, when I get home I'll see, but I think it will help me a lot.

Comment: Sorry buddy, but that's not what I need, I need to go through the array of vehicles, species and movies :(